# Apache rewrite sub2.domain.com/sub1/sub2 to sub2.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

How to rewrite so that the subfolders go away in the browser URL?

We have a new subdomain that is already in DNS going to a subfolder:

Entering sub2.domain.com changes the url in the browser to sub2.domain.com/sub1/sub2.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ sub1/sub2 [L]
```

I thought it's supposed to redirect first then rewrite? But this doesn't work:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sub1/sub2/.*$ http://sub2.domain.com/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub2\.domain.com/sub1/sub2$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub2\.domain\.com [L]
```

Comment: Why do you want such a thing ? You are making a loop. Anyway there is an error in the second RewriteCond, the HTTP_POST concerns only the domain, you can't access folders through it.